# Alerts set on shared calendar events (not alerting the share-ee)

Tags: ical

I have been searching for this and can't figure it out. If I create a calendar event and set the alert - my family gets notified of the event and can see it in their calendar. However, the attached alert doesn't transfer. I assume that is by design but in our case we'd like the alert to transfer with the event.
Anyone know how my family can get an alert-already-set event on their shared apple calendar?

Comment: IDK if this is the answer, but I found a 'way' to make this happen. If the receiver sets their calendar preferences to have a default alert of X minutes/hours - then any new event that comes in via a shared calendar will inherit that alert.